# jQuery with ajaxify form field

Tags: 7, javascript, ajax

I write a small module which calculate 2 values out of nodes and print it in a block with two form fields. One with the value as markup and the other is a ajax checkbox that switch through the two values.

Now I want to count up it with jquery. Onetime if the position of the form is reached and than when the checkbox is clicked. I don't get it. Everytime the value is wrong after clicked the checkbox or the value is emty after running the script. The script works well with a single value or the first given value, but not with the ajax callback.

```
    $(window).scroll(onScroll);
    $(document).ready(onScroll);            
    var squareMeters = $('.square-meters').text();

    //Drupal.behaviors.mymodule = {
    //attach: function(context, settings) { 
        //$('#counter input').click(function() {
        $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
            squareMeters = $('.square-meters').closest('#counter').find('.square-meters').text();

                $('.print-counter').countTo({
                    from: 0,
                    to: squareMeters,
                    speed: 4000,
                    refreshInterval: 50,
                    onComplete: function(value) {
                        console.debug(this);

                    }
                });
        });         
        //});
    //}};       

    function onScroll(event){
        //EDIT
        squareMeters = $('.square-meters').text();
        // EDIT END
        if(scrollPos <= posSM) {
            $('.print-counter').countTo({
                from: 0,
                to: squareMeters,
                speed: 4000,
                refreshInterval: 50,
                onComplete: function(value) {
                    console.debug(this);

                }
            });
        };

};
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a big flaw. The script works now with the changes. I mark it in my post.